# Linux Mint: Normal boot after login turns screen black

Tags: boot, linux-mint, login

If I do a standard boot of Linux Mint, it goes to the Login Screen, but as soon as I login, it flashes the desktop then the entire screen switches off - including the back light. Luckily, if I boot to Recovery Mode then 'resume', Linux boots normally. The only not-normal thing is when I login from 'resume' In recovery mode, there are strange shapes that appear on the screen made up from the desktop icons and picture.

Some things which I have tried:

- Running the various options in Recovery Mode
- Re-installing mate-screensaver
- Upgrading the entire system
- Deleting Heavy Duty apps - E.g. TeamViewer
- Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- Running `sudo apt-get install -f`

None of these things have worked.

2 Commands to show my system info:
`lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'`

Outputs:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 0a)`

Running:

```
inxi -Fxz
```

Outputs:

```
System:
  Host: *removed* Kernel: 4.15.0-54-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  compiler: gcc v: 7.4.0 Desktop: MATE 1.20.1 Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa 
  base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80TL v: Lenovo V110-15ISK 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0J40700 WIN serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: LENOVO v: 1KCN39WW date: 09/07/2017 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 29.3 Wh condition: 29.3/32.0 Wh (92%) 
  model: LGC L15L4A02 status: Full 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i3-6006U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Skylake rev: 3 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 15936 
  Speed: 500 MHz min/max: 400/2000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 459 2: 464 
  3: 403 4: 458 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 520 vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: fbdev,intel 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1366x768~76Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.2 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Lenovo 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-54-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth driver: iwlwifi 
  v: kernel port: efa0 bus ID: 02:00.0 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 119.24 GiB used: 27.58 GiB (23.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Intel model: SSDSC2KF128G8L size: 119.24 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 33.83 GiB used: 27.55 GiB (81.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 51.0 C mobo: 37.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 189 Uptime: 11h 59m Memory: 3.65 GiB used: 912.6 MiB (24.4%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.4.0 Shell: bash v: 4.4.20 
  inxi: 3.0.27
```

Any Ideas?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have fixed the problem. Booting with the '[nomodeset](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boot_options.html)' option fixed everything, for more details, have a look at [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) page.